# having no output for Gstatus in vim-fugitive plugin for vim

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I having a problem using fugitive-vim plugin, I have no idea what is Gdiff trying to show me, but not a diff for sure, but I can't even see a status. Im doing the same as in vimcast, and what common sence tell me to do - just enter Gstatus as a command, but its just blank new window appearing and nothing there, except status line tells me that i'm in looking at .git/index.

Its installed via bundle, I saw issues with it with solution to update - it is the latest version of 2.2, my git version is 2.2.2, may be its because it can't work with this version of git?

P.S. For example Gblame works great. And if it can help anyhow - my fish shell command prompt can successfully show me a branch of a directory.

SOLUTION UPDATE:

Ok, if anyone had the same issue - I'm happily solved it myself. The thing was in fish shell - it is not POSIX compatible, and I'm assuming that its the case. If you place in your .vimrc `set shell=/bin/bash` all works as it should be. So it is solved.

Comment: [Sensible.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) even changes `'shell'` if your shell is set to fish.

Comment: Please submit an answer to your own question so that others can learn from this

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if anyone had the same issue - I'm happily solved it myself. The thing was in fish shell - it is not POSIX compatible, and I'm assuming that its the case. If you place in your .vimrc set `shell=/bin/bash` all works as it should be. So it is solved.